# Ruby Datetime parse error with different format

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, datetime

I want to convert string to DateTime object which is in different format "13:54 25/02/2016", Is there any way to do this?

I've tried different ways, but getting error. I'm using ruby version '2.1.2'

Example:

```
DateTime.parse("13:54 25/02/2016") # ArgumentError: invalid date
DateTime.strptime("13:54 25/02/2016") ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.parse("13:54 25/02/2016")` is returning 
`Thu, 25 Feb 2016 13:54:00 +0000` in my rails console.Not sure why you have an argument error.

If you want to use strptime, You need to do `DateTime.strptime("13:54 25/02/2016", '%H:%M %d/%m/%Y')` `#=> Thu, 25 Feb 2016 13:54:00 +0000`

Comment: DateTime.parse("13:54 25/02/2016") # ArgumentError: invalid date still I have an error. 
DateTime.strptime("13:54 25/02/2016", '%H:%M %d/%m/%Y') this is giving correct datetime object.

Comment: @Madhusudhan Try updating your rails version, i am using 2.2.3 and it works fine. Glad that my answer helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to specify the format, but it should work by default (I tried with 2.2.2) as well. For example:

```
2.2.2 :016 > DateTime.parse("13:54 25/02/2016", "%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")
 => #<DateTime: 2016-02-25T13:54:00+00:00 ((2457444j,50040s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Are you sure you are using the right date: `require date`? Maybe the `DateTime` class is opened and changed?

Comment: DateTime.parse("13:54 25/02/2016", "%H:%M %d/%m/%Y") # ArgumentError: invalid date
For strptime date format is mandatory, for parse also is it mandatory?

Comment: Can you check if `Kernel.const_defined?("DateTime")` is returning `false` _before_ you do `require date`? I am somehow having a feeling that you are using the unintended version of `DateTime`.

Comment: It is returning true

Answer (score 0):

`strptime` needs you to provide format of the date string:

```
strptime([string='-4712-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'[, format='%FT%T%z'[ ,start=ITALY]]])
```

Even if you know you provide the string in the default format, it is a good practice to explicit it.